# How to change image on mouseover in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

In Vue.js, I can bind an image to an img element:

```
<img v-bind:src="myimage" />
```

How can I define another image that is displayed when the mouse moves over this image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the value of `myImage` in a `mouseover` listener:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { 
      myImage: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/bd/5d/84/bd5d845c980508d41b0329dc21d08d2b.jpg",
      otherImage: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/03/29/09/17/cat-300572_960_720.jpg"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <img :src="myImage" @mouseover="myImage = otherImage"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I am unable to make mouseover work. Here is my simplified code: `code`<img :src="image" @mouseover="image_hover" />`code`. While the page displays the picture contained in **image**, it does not show the mouseover image contained in **image_url**. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is `image_url` the address of the image you want to show on mouseover? If so, does your `image_hover` method set `this.image = this.image_url`?

Comment: It is working now. Incidentally, when developer console is open, mouseover events were not firing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What if you have a relative url as `@/assets/images/yes.png` ? Doesn't work, I think